# How to send from server arbitrarily to a STOMP end point in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, kotlin, stomp

I'm writing a bridge application in SpringBoot two bridge an internal messaging protocol over to a websocket based stomp setup.  I'm operating in a mixed-mode `Kotlin`, `java` project (which "might" be making things difficult).

My goal is when I receive a message on our internal messaging queue, i wanted to send it over to the STOMP endpoints.

I can send from `STOMP->STOMP` and `REST->STOMP` but I seem unable to make the server send directly to a stomp endpoint correclty.

I've gone through just about every single stack post - and I see people have had similar issues, yet, I'm unable to actually get any of the listed solutions working.

From what I gather I need to add:

#### java

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;
```

#### kotlin

```
@Autowired
lateinit var template: SimpleMessagingTemplate
```

into one of my classes and either add `@Controller` or `@Service` to the top of the class, possibly making it `open` in `kotlin`

#### Attempts (java):

```
@Controller
public class STOMPDataListener implements SDDFDataListener {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;


    public void handleData(String source, SDDFCommonData data) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + data);
    }
}
```

If I add a breakpoint on my `handleData` call I find out that:

> template = null

#### Attempt (kotlin)

```
@Controller
class BridgeDataListener(val peerID: String = "default") : SDDFDataListener {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var template: SimpMessagingTemplate


    override fun handleData(source: String, data: SDDFCommonData) {
        println("Received: $data")
    }
}
```

> lateinit property template has not been initialized
>   [image]

If I mark it as

```
@Service
class BridgeDataListener(val peerID: String = "default") : SDDFDataListener {
```

I get the same error.

I know this is possible because in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html they give an example, however, I'm not sure how I could use this example directly because I need to construct multiple versions of my DataListeners - and from what I understand an @Autowired class you get one copy of only?  Could I make it a singleton or would that break something?

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public GreetingController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greetings", method=POST)
    public void greet(String greeting) {
        String text = "[" + getTimestamp() + "]:" + greeting;
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", text);
    }

}
```

Assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the `handleData` called i.e. how is the instance of `STOMPDataListener`/`BridgeDataListener` created? "Normally" when Spring cannot bind to a field an exception is thrown. Since it's not the case for you I suspect the instance is not created by Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So It looks like I ended up solving my issue.

`@Autowired` does not work if you instantiate a class with `new`.  As I was using some libraries I had to follow approach #3 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896871/2069812

So I built a java class:

```
/**
 * See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896871/2069812
 */
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

And then in my data handler class I accessed the bean via:

`var template: SimpMessagingTemplate = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(SimpMessagingTemplate::class.java)`

which allowed me to call:

```
 template.convertAndSend("/topic/sddf/$source", json.toString())
 template.convertAndSend("/topic/sddf/$source/$peerID", json.toString())
```